# Some doubts regarding linter in c++

Tags: c++, clion

My ide is showing linter error in the following code. It is highliting yellow in the int main() student s; part

```
using namespace std;

class student {
public:
    int age,DOB;
    char name[32];
    void getData() {
        cin >> age >> DOB >> name;
    }
    void display() {
        cout << name << ends << age << ends << DOB ;
    }
};

int main() {
    student s;
    s.getData();
    s.display();
}
```

and the following code which is same but on adding curlys after student s in the int main student part solves the problem

```
using namespace std;

class student {
public:
    int age,DOB;
    char name[32];
    void getData() {
        cin >> age >> DOB >> name;
    }
    void display() {
        cout << name << ends << age << ends << DOB ;
    }
};

int main() {
    student s{};
    s.getData();
    s.display();
}
```

Comment: Reading uninitialized variables is undefined behaviour. `s{}` will value-initialize all members. In your example it will zero-initialize them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your IDE most likely points out that the member variables of `s` are not initialized.

Using `{}` syntax ensures that it is initialized.

You can read more about typed of initialization in C++ [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization).

Answer (score 0):

Your IDE is most likely working with C++ 11.
This method is called as **extended initializer lists**
This syntax is not required in modern compilers
Try upgrading your IDE to ***Code blocks 17.12*** for C++ codes its very handy!!!

Comment: Nope I am using c++ 17. and @Rinat Veliakhmedov's answer has solved my query.